# Re-open file read-only in Linux (or POSIX)

Tags: c, linux, posix

I open a file in read/write mode and do a series of reads, writes and seeks (from user input).

At some point later on I want to make the file read-only to prevent any further writes to it.

Is there a Linux (or POSIX) function to do that? Perhaps some `fcntl` call?

Or is my only option is to save the current position in the file, close it and reopen `RD_ONLY`?

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fd = open("/path/to/file", O_RDWR);

// mixture of:
write(fd, ...);
lseek(fd, ...);
read (fd, ...);
// etc

...

// make file read-only ???

read (fd, ...); // OK
lseek(fd, ...); // OK
write(fd, ...); // error
```

Comment: Does this work? `fcntl(fd,  F_SETFL, O_RDONLY)`

Comment: @jackarms: “File access mode (`O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, `O_RDWR`) … flags in `arg` are ignored.”

Comment: At least [one resource](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Access-Modes.html) believes “the access modes are chosen when the file is opened, and never change”.

Comment: Hmm yes just looked up that detail for myself. It appears there is no standard way of changing permissions of a descriptor.

Comment: I though you could do what you wanted with `fchmod` but actually running a quick test showed it did not work. Looks like `read` and `write` on my system (macOS/darwin) only really cares about the mode set by `open` as mentioned by the source linked to by @Ryan above. So it looks like close and reopen, even though you were hoping for a more elegant solution might be the safest way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible at least through call to `fcntl` as the POSIX docs says (emphasis is mine):

> `fcntl()`:
>
> **F_SETFL**
>
> Set the file status flags, defined in `fcntl.h`, for the file
>   description associated with fildes from the corresponding bits in the
>   third argument, arg, taken as type int. **Bits corresponding to the file
>   access mode and the file creation flags, as defined in `fcntl.h`, that
>   are set in arg shall be ignored**. If any bits in arg other than those
>   mentioned here are changed by the application, the result is
>   unspecified.

and

> `fcntl.h`
>
> **O_ACCMODE** Mask for file access modes.
>
> The  header shall define the
>   following symbolic constants for use as the file access modes for
>   open(), openat(), and fcntl(). The values shall be unique, except that
>   **O_EXEC** and **O_SEARCH** may have equal values. The values shall be
>   suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives.
>
> **O_EXEC** Open for execute only (non-directory files). The result is
>   unspecified if this flag is applied to a directory.
>
> **O_RDONLY** Open for
>   reading only.
>
> **O_RDWR** Open for reading and writing.
>
> **O_SEARCH** Open
>   directory for search only. The result is unspecified if this flag is
>   applied to a non-directory file.
>
> **O_WRONLY** Open for writing only.